# Direction building an iphone card game

Tags: iphone, ios4, playing-cards

I have some exposure building iphone apps but have never tried to build a game before. I am trying to build a card game (not like poker, blackjack etc.) more like quick cards where player will be presented with one card at a time. Player selects an option on the card and that card is put back in stack and is replaced by a new card.
I need some direction going about it and I have some questions:

1. Is there an example out there? I looked into GeekGameBoard but that is more like the 52 cards game play. For my game, the card occupies the whole screen and is replaced by a new one from the stack.
2. Can I use Gamesalad or Cocos2d to build something like this faster? Since I would have to have some animation and game logic, I am wondering if this will help me do some common stuff faster.
3. What is the best practice for data interaction for card based games in general? Use CoreData or plists as the game is played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't know, if you really need an example, maybe you should think back on what you need, write down algorithms and data structures, etc...
2. It really depends on what you have in mind... CoreAnimation can get you quite far for that kind of game, but if you want something really rich (think complex animations, music + sound, particles for special effects, things like that), you'd be better off using Cocos2d.
3. I would think CoreData is overkill for that kind of stuff. If you're really familiar with it, maybe. I'd probably create some classes to handle that, think Model in a MVC pattern.